# Increase timeout of HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout, httprequest

I need to do an async HttpRequest to a web service on a remote computer. This request can potentially need more than 60s which seems to be the default timeout of the HttpRequest. I can set the timeout property at the HttpRequest object, but unfortunately the Timeout property has no effect on asynchronous requests made with the BeginGetResponse or BeginGetRequestStream method (refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx).

Does anyone know how I can increase the timeout anyway so that I don't get an exception after 60 seconds?